# Get webcams names in Xuggler library on Windows

Tags: java, video, webcam, xuggler

When I using Xuggler library on computer with more than one web-camera with Windows I need use "name" of this web-cameras to select device. I means that command "vfwcap 0" select only first web-camera and command "vfwcap 1" or "vfwcap 2" not allowed get access to other web-cameras. If I use:

```
$ ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

I can see the list of "names" this web-cameras. For example: "Logitech HD Webcam C270", "Logitech Webcam C210". If I using this names into the Xuggler library I get en error.

So, I can get access only to the first web-camera on Windows machine using Xuggler.

**Can I get list of all devices in Windows from Xuggler and can I use this names into the Xuggler (I just want to use more than one web-camera at the same time)?**

Maybe alternative way are exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this simple java program, you can get list of all webcam's available on your system.

```
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam;

public class CameraTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Webcam> list = Webcam.getWebcams();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                try {
                    Webcam cam = list.get(i);
                    System.out.println("Found this Camera : "+cam.getName());
                    BufferedImage image = cam.getImage();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception in cam : " + i);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample Output :**

```
Found this Camera : TV CARD WDM VIDEO CAPTURE 0
Found this Camera : ManyCam Video Source 1
Found this Camera : DroidCam 2
```

You will have List of all camera's , So you can use anyone of them as you like.

Comment: Mohammad, thank you very much! It is not Xuggler native way, but it is very useful library for me!